# Using One Hot Encoder

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn

I have two questions regarding the scikit-learn OHE method :

1. why one hot encoder doesn't accept one dimensional data while it works perfectly if we just reshaped our data to `(nrows,1)`?
2. what does (drop=first, binary, etc.) actually does and what will happen if we just set the value to None?

Answer (score 1):

You could use a read of the documentation.

https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.OneHotEncoder.html

1. "categories: ‘auto’ or a list of array-like"
2. "drop: {‘first’, ‘if_binary’} or a array-like of shape (n_features,), default=None
   Specifies a methodology to use to drop one of the categories per
   feature. This is useful in situations where perfectly collinear
   features cause problems, such as when feeding the resulting data
   into a neural network or an unregularized regression.
   However, dropping one category breaks the symmetry of the original representation and can therefore induce a bias in downstream models, for instance for penalized linear classification or regression models.

- None : retain all features (the default).
- ‘first’ : drop the first category in each feature. If only one category is present, the feature will be dropped entirely.
- ‘if_binary’ : drop the first category in each feature with two categories. Features with 1 or more than 2 categories are left intact.
- array : drop[i] is the category in feature X[:, i] that should be dropped.

Comment: Hey Charpentier thanks for helping out. Kindly reread my question :)